# Access my foscam camera on my home from the Internet - using ssh tunnels

Tags: tunneling

Recently I bought a Foscam wireless IP camera:
http://www.foscam.com/Products_List.asp?id=173

In my home, my laptop and my IP camera are behind a cable modem (my ISP gives me a dynamic IP) using a linksys router (I dont have a public IP).

Actually I use SSH in a basic way to learn / manage some basic things in my VPS server.

My question is (the right ssh flags and commands to achieve this):

I think that I need to create:

1. A tunnel from my local router to a remote VPS server where I have root access.
2. A portforward in the router.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you able to access the camera using HTTPS ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a port forward in your router from port X to port 22 on your home computer.

You can then `ssh -p X username@your-home-ip`.

Include the `-L Y:foscamip:80` command line switch when you run ssh, assuming focscam runs a web server on port 80 (standard). Use something over 1024 for Y, like 8080.

Open up a web browser, and go to `http://localhost:Y`.

You have access! When you're done, simply log out of your ssh session.

Comment: Im a litle confused, where exactly is stablished the tunnel from my local router 
to the remote VPS server?

Comment: oh, sorry. I thought the objective was to view an http webpage shown by a webcam from somewhere outside your house. Could you clarify what you plan on using the camera for?

Comment: Now for testing, in a few weeks (my two weeks vacations) to remotely watch my apartment from remote internet connections or my android browser. Thanks.

Comment: This would allow you to access your camera's webpage from any remote unix. The equivalent for windows is usually [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/), the local tunnel option under ssh is the same as the -L command line switch

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I will answer in the hope it helps someone like me. Given:

- you have a VPS with root access at root@example.com
- you have an RTSP-compatible IP camera in your LAN at address 192.168.1.100
- you have a PC/router/Raspberry Pi able to create the tunnel

what I did was

`ssh -N -f -R 10554:192.168.1.100:554 root@example.com`

Exaplanation:

- `-N`: don't execute any command via SSH
- `-f`: put SSH in the background
- `-R`: remote port forwarding
- `10554`: a port to open on the VPS to access the IP camera (better if > 1024)
- `192.168.1.100:554`: IP address and port you want to access remotely
- `root@example.com`: user and address of your VPS

To access the RTSP stream of the camera, open `rtsp://<username>:<password>@example.com:10554/<path-to-stream>`.

Of course it works fine also for other kind of streams (e.g. HTTP).

Better yet, use autossh.

`/usr/bin/autossh -N -f -M 0 -i /home/pi/.ssh/id_rsa -o "ServerAliveInterval 30" -o "ServerAliveCountMax 3" -R 10554:192.168.1.100:554 root@example.com`.

I ended up with this command reading a lot of articles on the web. I even created an `autossh` user on the VPS without a shell, so it can do nothing apart from port forwarding.