# Access network camera from outside LAN without port forwarded

Tags: javascript, html, raspberry-pi, webrtc

I have raspberryPi camera with mjpeg stream to show live streaming. Right now when I create a web-server inside the local network I am able to see the live stream on web browser using simple html `iframe`. Now I need to move my webserver to public server and I will not be able to do port forwarding with raspberryPi to show the live on web-page.

Is there any way to stream a video feed to we-browser where the server is publicly accessible.
I have found the webRTC. Is there any quicker why available to make stream a camera feed to website. That is peer to peer connection between a web Browser and raspbarryPi  where no port forwarding can be do at raspbarryPi.

Comment: Why not publish your stream to your web server?  HLS or DASH.

Comment: Can you please elaborate, my web server is at godaddy, with html/css/js to display live feed.

Comment: Install FFmpeg, use it to output an HLS manifest (.m3u8) and media segments (.ts).  Then, use the tool of your choice to upload these files to your web server up at GoDaddy.  Then on your page, use HLS.js as your player to play those files.  https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js/

Comment: Network cameras can only broadcast inside LAN - outside your LAN consumers must use unicast which requires that your camera can be reached either on a public IP or port-forwarded to a non-public IP.

Comment: Actually I am using RPI csi camera for this purpose, some thing like this https://tutorials-raspberrypi.com/raspberry-pi-security-camera-livestream-setup/

Comment: @Brad Actually I couldn't upload to godaddy, I have to create some peer-peer connection between client browser ad Rpi

Comment: @CodeDezk Your question states that you're moving everything to a public web server, so why can't your video go there as well?  The only real other option is WebRTC which is going to require a signalling server as some kind, and a TURN server in some cases.

Comment: I mean the webpage will move to public server, and the RPI camera will be in local network.

Comment: Yes I have worked with it, and tested some sample with peerjs, but I am confused how I can start working with webRTC with RPI, how I can start stream from RPi when client browser request, since RPI doesn't have any public access how the stream can be initiated.

Answer (score 2):

**Make port public using [ngrok.com](https://ngrok.com/)**

This tool can make a port publicly accessible without router access. It creates a link from where you can see your current link to your webcam. The free version of ngrok do have some limitations like that max amount of new connections per minute.

**Port forwarding through VPS using ssh**

In Godaddy you can also create an ubuntu system. You can open ports on this system for it to be accessible from anywhere. Then on your raspberry-pi you can run `ssh -L [public-port]:localhost:[private-port]  [youruser]@[server-ip]`  example: `ssh -L 3000:localhost:3000 myuser@mywebsite.com`. This would make your project on the raspberry pi on port 3000 be accessible with "mywebsite.com:3000"

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, can you please elaborate ssh way, right now I have apache server installed in Ubuntu 16.04 and which is publicly accessible. How can show my rasobarry project with Ubuntu Public webserver, any reference.

Comment: @CodeDezk Here is a link that explains how to connect to your ubuntu server. Godaddy apparently already has everything setup. Then you can use the command above to forward a port. I also recommend using autossh as it reconnects in case there is an interruption in your connection. https://uk.godaddy.com/help/connect-to-my-web-hosting-account-with-ssh-secure-shell-4943   https://handyman.dulare.com/ssh-tunneling-with-autossh/

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question, but will answer for the late me.
I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4610979/access-my-foscam-camera-on-my-home-from-the-internet-using-ssh-tunnels). It boils down to:

`/usr/bin/autossh -N -f -M 0 -i /home/pi/.ssh/id_rsa -o "ServerAliveInterval 30" -o "ServerAliveCountMax 3" -R 10554:192.168.1.100:554 root@example.com`

where:

- `-N`: don't execute any command via SSH
- `-f`: put SSH in the background
- `-R`: remote port forwarding
- `10554`: a port to open on the VPS to access the IP camera (better if > 1024)
- `192.168.1.100:554`: IP address and port you want to access remotely
- `root@example.com`: user and address of your VPS

To access the RTSP stream of the camera, open `rtsp://<username>:<password>@example.com:10554/<path-to-stream>`.

Of course it works fine also for other kind of streams (e.g. HTTP).